# Javascript/ExtendScript adding a menu item after the help tab

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm creating a new menu item but have a few problems with the placement of it.

I can place it on every position in the main menu but not after the help menu.

Can anyone explain why this is not possible? I don't get an error but the menu just won't pop-up.

This is how I get the menu:

`app.menus.item( '$ID/Main' ).submenus.item( '$ID/&Window' );`

Hope anyone can make some sense out of this.

Comment: Should not this be item( '$ID/&Help' )? It is difficult to help without looking at your code. Post some more code, please.

Comment: Yeah thought of that but that doesn't show the menu at all. This is the entire code https://pastebin.com/AZkqbLNQ